# How to Implement search with Rails Mailboxer?

Tags: ruby

I want to integrate search feature for the **rails mailboxer**, they have no documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a lot more information to get anything close to a decent answer. I believe this is referring to the [Mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) gem.

It looks like this gem uses standard ActiveRecord models at it's core (https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/tree/master/app/models), so you should be able to query them as you would normally. Try using the [ActiveRecord query methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on your messages